# how to run my form that i have created in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-form

i have created a form to automate a task in outlook  how i run the form like if want it as executable or icon on the desktop which on clicking will run my form

Answer (score 0):

lets say my userform name is userform1

then i call my form from my macro-

```
sub monitorbox()
    userform1.show
end sub
```

now i add this macro as button to my outlook tool bar by

going to tools | customize | command tab

go to macro and then drag to tool bar

that is it u r done.